# Parametric Curve Fitting Using Python

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting, bezier, spline

I wanted to bestfit a parametric curve to a set of points. The beginning and end of the curve should coincide with a first and last sample point respectively.

I have tried this code below, but it is giving me a closed curve. Is there a way to modify this code slightly to ensure the curve is not closed?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x = np.array([23, 24, 24, 25, 25])
y = np.array([13, 12, 13, 12, 13])

# append the starting x,y coordinates
x = np.r_[x, x[0]]
y = np.r_[y, y[0]]

# fit splines to x=f(u) and y=g(u), treating both as periodic. also note that s=0
# is needed in order to force the spline fit to pass through all the input points.
tck, u = interpolate.splprep([x, y], s=0, per=True)

# evaluate the spline fits for 1000 evenly spaced distance values
xi, yi = interpolate.splev(np.linspace(0, 1, 1000), tck)

# plot the result
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.plot(x, y, 'or')
ax.plot(xi, yi, '-b')'''
```

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

You are appending the first x and y values to the end of the x and y arrays:

```
# append the starting x,y coordinates
x = np.r_[x, x[0]]
y = np.r_[y, y[0]]
```

..which means that you want the spline to end the same place that it starts, and then you are telling the `interpolate.splprep` function that you want a periodic curve with the `per=True` keyword argument:

```
tck, u = interpolate.splprep([x, y], per=True, s=0)
```

..which will give you exactly what you get..:

[image: result before modification]

Just remove the two lines where you append the last x and y values to the x and y arrays and remove the `per=True` keyword argument and you get what you are asking for:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x = np.array([23, 24, 24, 25, 25])
y = np.array([13, 12, 13, 12, 13])

# append the starting x,y coordinates
# x = np.r_[x, x[0]]
# y = np.r_[y, y[0]]

# fit splines to x=f(u) and y=g(u), treating both as periodic. also note that s=0
# is needed in order to force the spline fit to pass through all the input points.
# tck, u = interpolate.splprep([x, y], per=True, s=0)
tck, u = interpolate.splprep([x, y], s=0)

# evaluate the spline fits for 1000 evenly spaced distance values
xi, yi = interpolate.splev(np.linspace(0, 1, 1000), tck)

# plot the result
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.plot(x, y, 'or')
ax.plot(xi, yi, '-b')
plt.show()
```

[image: result after modification]